# Working for a company I co-own in the US while in France (and student visas...)

Tags: france, student-visa, working, paperwork

I am applying for a student visa to take French classes and then (hopefully) enter a 1 year Masters program in Paris. My husband and I co-own a business together here in the US, and the required part of my monthly income will be coming from that business. Because it's still fairly new and until recently I was also running a nonprofit that paid me a salary, I have not taken a salary or a draw from it before. I plan to continue supporting the business around 30 hours per month.

1. Are there any legal issues with working remotely like this for a business you own? It's a small manufacturing business, and I'll be working on strategy, overseeing marketing, writing quotes, doing the monthly reconciliation, etc--the parts that can be done a continent away.
2. Is it better to call this an "owners draw" or perhaps a "monthly owners dividend" rather than a salary on the visa application?
3. If they want historic proof of this salary, the bank account won't show it because it's new. Since I'm a co-owner and can't request an official letter from my "manager"...can I just write a letter for myself stating that that's what I'll be getting? Perhaps on the official letterhead I created a while back? ;)

If I didn't need to show that I could support myself, I would probably just keep it on the down-low for the application to not over-complicate things. But as it is...

Thanks so much for any help or insights that you can provide! I'm feeling very stumped at the moment.

Comment: Another option: arrange your finances during your time in  France so your husband is paying, not you.

Comment: @user19323 I’d suggest you provide a cash flow and the latest CPA-certified financial accounts for the business to show that it’s sufficiently profitable to support your intended drawings.

Comment: @phoog That could be an option. I'm not sure how to show that exactly, but I'll keep researching. To make it more complex, we are separating but haven't officially done anything about that, so there wouldn't be a paperwork trail.

Comment: @Traveller Since it's a family-owned business that is just barely profitable (hence why I'm only taking out the required $700 or so instead of a larger salary), I'm not sure if that would help or hinder *laughs nervously*. But that's a great suggestion; I will run the numbers to see if it will work! Thank you.